# How to install AGIC in Kubernetes cluster using Terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to install AGIC in AKS using Terraform. I am following this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/terraform/terraform-create-k8s-cluster-with-aks-applicationgateway-ingress but this document shows partial terraform deployment i want to fully automate it with the help of Terraform. Is there any other document/way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you can use the Terraform to deploy the Helm charts to the AKS. And here is an example for deploying Helm charts through Terraform:

```
data "helm_repository" "stable" {
  name = "stable"
  url  = "https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com"
}

resource "helm_release" "example" {
  name       = "my-redis-release"
  repository = data.helm_repository.stable.metadata[0].name
  chart      = "redis"
  version    = "6.0.1"

  values = [
    "${file("values.yaml")}"
  ]

  set {
    name  = "cluster.enabled"
    value = "true"
  }

  set {
    name  = "metrics.enabled"
    value = "true"
  }

  set_string {
    name  = "service.annotations.prometheus\\.io/port"
    value = "9127"
  }
}
```

And you can also configure the certificate of the AKS to deploy the Helm charts through Terraform, take a look at the document [here](https://gaunacode.com/creating-and-setting-up-an-aks-cluster-through-terraform).

Comment: What about AAD Pod identity through terraform?

Comment: also i tried this method for installing helm but getting an error for values.yaml file

Comment: @SiddhiMorajkar It probably caused by your helm chart. Check if it's all right. And AAD Pod? It creates the pods as normal, just combines the service principal with the pods. You just need to do as usual.

Comment: Okay, i will chrck again

Comment: @SiddhiMorajkar Wait for the result. Any questions are free. And if works for you, please accept it :-)

Comment: Yes, will surely try this

Comment: i am using  ingress-azure chart and when i run the above code, i get  - Error: execution error at (ingress-azure/templates/configmap.yaml:1:7): A valid appgw entry is required!

Comment: @SiddhiMorajkar It's the requirements of the ingress-azure chart. It needs some information about the application gateway. You can follow the steps when uses [the existing one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ingress-controller-install-existing) or [create a new one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ingress-controller-install-new).

Comment: Currently i am making using of 'null_resource' to install the ingress controller. But while doing so, i need to edit the helm-config.yaml values manually. Is there any way such that the required values are automatically updated.

Comment: @SiddhiMorajkar Why not use the Helm provider? This is your question that you ask? And in this way, you just need to set the values with the set block.